# How do I translate "overtake"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I checked Reta Vortaro and got no hits, Google translate proposed "preterpasi".

I'm looking for meaning 1.b. "to catch up with and pass by" according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overtake), so preterpasi is probably the best translation. I wasn't aware that it could be just "catch up with", but the second meaning "to come upon suddenly" seems easy to translate. It's a word with a lot of meanings.

Other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[John Wells’ dictionary](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) has the following:

> **overtake** preter-veturi, -atingi, -pasi, devanci

I think in the general sense *preterpasi* seems good and is the word I would have chosen too. Perhaps *preterveturi* could be used if you wanted to be more precise when talking about overtaking someone on the road.

I wasn’t aware of the meaning “catch up with” either, but perhaps that is the one Wells is trying to capture with *preteratingi*.

I don’t think I’ve ever heard *devanci*. It has 6 hits in the tekstaro, wheras *preterpasi* has over a hundred (by default it stops searching after 100). I can’t think of a reason to use that over *preterpasi*. The latter has the advantage of being fairly self-explanatory even if you’ve never heard it.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use *transpasi* for this meaning.

Comment: Dankon! Mi ne audis antaue, sed havas sencon kaj estas komprenebla.